# Retrieve bounded time periods as a step function where beginning of period returns 1, end of period returns 0

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, sql-server-2008-r2, common-table-expression

I have a table in Microsoft SQL Server called `Downtime` that looks like this (I have omitted some irrelevant columns and many entries):

| ID | StartTime | EndTime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 2024-03-27 09:07:20.653 | 2024-03-27 09:09:07.690 |
| 17 | 2024-03-27 09:59:50.557 | 2024-03-27 10:59:50.137 |
| 24 | 2024-03-27 11:04:07.497 | 2024-03-27 11:07:02.657 |

I need to write a query that turns the above data into this format:

| t_stamp | CurrentlyDown |
| --- | --- |
| 2024-03-27 09:07:20.653 | 1 |
| 2024-03-27 09:09:07.690 | 0 |
| 2024-03-27 09:59:50.557 | 1 |
| 2024-03-27 10:59:50.137 | 0 |
| 2024-03-27 11:04:07.497 | 1 |
| 2024-03-27 11:07:02.657 | 0 |

In words, this query should split each original entry into two entries (one `t_stamp` for `StartTime` and one `t_stamp` for `EndTime`) and return a value (`CurrentlyDown`) of 1 (if `t_stamp` is from the `StartTime` column) or 0 (if `t_stamp` is from the `EndTime` column).

I can think to try two things:

- A self join around the ID field with a `CASE` statement checking the timestamp fields
- Two CTE's (one focused on grabbing StartTimes and the other focused on EndTimes) with a final query to join these two CTE's together around the ID column. Maybe just one CTE is needed here?

I am concerned with performance so I want to do this as efficiently as possible. I am far from a SQL expert, so I don't really know which path is best to take (if either).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one option using `CROSS APPLY`

**Example**

```
Select B.* 
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Apply ( values (StartTime,1)
                     ,(EndTime  ,0)
             ) B(t_stamp,currentlydown)
```

**Results**

```
t_stamp                   currentlydown
2024-03-27 09:07:20.653   1
2024-03-27 09:09:07.690   0
2024-03-27 09:59:50.557   1
2024-03-27 10:59:50.137   0
2024-03-27 11:04:07.497   1
2024-03-27 11:07:02.657   0
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need. Working great on my end. Thank you!